# cassandra timeuuid columns showing buffer type data insted of string

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql, timeuuid

I am retrieving data from Cassandra timeuuid column using NodeJS Cassandra driver. Now the data retrieved as buffer type instead of string type. I need the data as string type

Comment: Show us what you already tried. Maybe we can help.

Comment: Previously "select PostedDate from facehq.timeline"  returns the value "posteddate":"f6ca25d0-ffa4-11e4-830a-b395dbb548cd" now it is returning value "posteddate":{"buffer":[122,60,208,167,80,165,17,229,135,100,140,199,127,17,202,49]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's still difficult to understand what you're expecting to see, this will return your `PostedDate` in a more-readable format:

```
SELECT DateOf(PostedDate) FROM facehq.timeline;
```

Also, as your data grows in size, unbound queries will become problematic and slow.  So make sure you qualify queries like this with a WHERE clause whenever possible.

> i need result like "posteddate":"f6ca25d0-ffa4-11e4-830a-b395dbb548cd".

It sounds to me like your issue is in your node.js code.  How are you executing your query?  The [Node.js driver documentation on the GitHub project page](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver) has an example that may help:

```
client.stream('SELECT time, val FROM temperature WHERE station_id=', ['abc'])
  .on('readable', function () {
    //readable is emitted as soon a row is received and parsed
    var row;
    while (row = this.read()) {
      console.log('time %s and value %s', row.time, row.val);
    }
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    //stream ended, there aren't any more rows
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    //Something went wrong: err is a response error from Cassandra
  });
```

The DataStax documentation also has a specific example for [working with timeUUIDs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/2.2/nodejs-driver/reference/uuids-timeuuids.html):

```
client.execute('SELECT id, timeid FROM sensor', function (err, result) {
    assert.ifError(err);
    console.log(result.rows[0].timeid instanceof TimeUuid); // true
    console.log(result.rows[0].timeid instanceof Uuid); // true, it inherits from Uuid
    console.log(result.rows[0].timeid.toString());      // <- xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    console.log(result.rows[0].timeid.getDate());       // <- Date stored in the identifier
});
```

Comment: For the "select PostedDate from facehq.timeline" i need result like  "posteddate":"f6ca25d0-ffa4-11e4-830a-b395dbb548cd".

Now the result is "posteddate":{"buffer":[122,60,208,167,80,165,17,229,135,100,140,199,127,17,202,‌​49]}

Comment: @Prorammer81 [When using `console.log`, the object is inspected, so it shows the attributes of the object](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) Make sure to update to the latest version, in latest version of the driver, each type has `inspect()` method implemented, printing a nice "TimeUuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" and [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) method. Anyhow, `toString()` is what you are looking for, the string representation of a TimeUuid.